# Spring Integration - convert XML payload to JSON

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am creating a generic adapter which would take XML message (with namepace) and convert it to JSON. I can remove the namespace using xslt and then use org.json api to conver to JSON and there are some other transformation and using the SI flow -

```
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(org.springframework.integration.jms.dsl.Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                        org.springframework.integration.jms.dsl.Jms.container(this.queueConnFactory, this.queue)
                                .transactionManager(transactionManager()).get()))
                .transform(dynamicEnricherImpl.get(enricherName), "enrich")
                .handle(publisher, "publishMessage")
                .get();
```

I am looking if the same can be achieved using SPring Integration inner classes like ObjectToJSON transformer to remove the XML namespace and convert it to JSON. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you really do a conversion from XML to JSON. Would you mind to share some sample with your XSLT and that `org.json`? And of course, with an original XML and final JSON.

What I would do in Spring Integration is something like `UnmarshallingTransformer` where we create some domain model from the XML using `Marshaller` abstraction.

Then when we have already a Java POJO it is easy to call the mentioned `ObjectToJsonTransformer` and you'll get a JSON on the output.

It is also possible to apply a `XPathTransformer` to get some value from the XML and so on.

Please, read more about XML support in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.M4/reference/html/xml.html#xml